# How do I control the snippet text that shows up for my question in list view?

Tags: support, question-lists

I asked a question today and noticed that rather than taking the text at the beginning of the question to display under the question title in the list view, SO is grabbing some code from the middle of the question:

[image]

Here's the question:

[Android override all button styles except dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193818/android-override-all-button-styles-except-dialogs)

That summary certainly does not draw the reader in to want to see more.  I would be likely to just skip it because I prefer questions where the asker introduces the question with some explanatory text and this looks like it could just be a code dump with "please help" at the end.  How do I improve the display of this question?

Comment: It looks fine from here. Doesn't grab from the middle.

Comment: In the list view it doesn't look like my screenshot?

Comment: I get it like this: http://prntscr.com/cxr57u

Comment: Strange I wonder why it was different for me. Well, thank you.